# tf override gradients based on current gradients for differential functions

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation

Is it possible to change the gradients propagating back to the optimizer based on the the current gradients?
I.e

```
intermediate_layer = build_intermediate(inputs)
outputs = conv2d(intermediate_layer)
#####
   ## And for all the variables inside intermediate
gradients_that_propagate_to_optimizer = true_gradients * 2
```

I know that tf has `RegisterGradient` but I didn't find a way to use the computed gradients to calculate the custom ones.

Comment: To change how the gradient is computed for some operations, you may use [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient). To manipulate the gradients used by the optimizer, you can call [`tf.train.Optimizer.compute_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients), manipulate the gradient values and then call [`tf.train.Optimizer.apply_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#apply_gradients) (instead of calling `minimize`).